# Proportion of time non-renewables determine the price of electricity price

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, resource-economics, nonrenewable-resources

I have a long time-series dataset of electricity generation over a period, broken down by generation type renewable and non renewable. I want to determine the percentage of time that non-renewables are the determinant of the price of electricity. The variables in the dataset include non-renewable generation, renewable generation, and total supply. There is no pricing data. Can any help me with this problem?